# Repeat input type file by taking integer input from user

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

So, basically i have a textbox and file upload button . What i want when user enter integer in textbox for eg :10 then i want to display file upload button 10 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo hope it will helpful for you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 
function AppendRow(e) {
    var val = e.value;
    if (val !== "") {
      var html ='';
        for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
          html +='<input type="file" id="file">';
        }
     $("#append").empty().append(html);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 

<input  type="text" id="input1" onkeyup="AppendRow(this)"/> 
 <div id="append">
 
 <div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for sharing this.
But it would be great if you  could  give it to me answer in type script(angular6)

Comment: sorry, but I do not know angular you added a jquery tag so I answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
        if (val !== "") {
          var html;
            for (var i = 0; i < val; i++) {
              html = '<input type="file" id="file">';
              $("#append").append(html);
            }
         
        }
    });
});
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
     

    <input  type="text" id="input" /> 
     <div id="append">
     
     </div>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="count" />
<div *ngFor="let item of [].constructor(count); ">
  <input type='file'>
</div>
```